# Execute a shell command directly in a sandbox

Tags: security, command-line-interface, sandbox, unsafe

Someone has an idea to execute unsafe command with a binary ?

On GitHub, Nbareil developped this tool :
[seccomp-nurse](https://github.com/nbareil/seccomp-nurse)

But I experiment some difficult to use it

(The error :)

```
$ ./sandbox -- ls
 sandbox.action ERROR: syscall NR_restart_syscall [nr=0x0] not implemented
```

Have you an alternative ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)?

Comment: @strzel_a unsecure isn't a word,  and if setup properly chroots can be **very** secure.